# HTML5 audio playbackRate property is not working for mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

$('#audioPlayerControl').playbackRate=1.5;

$('#audioPlayerControl') is audio element and i set playbackRate for this audio element. desktop chrome browser it working application but it is working properly but mobile chrome browser it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely guesstimate without any further context is that the mobile browser simply doesn't support [the HTMLMediaElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#AutoCompatibilityTable).

Comment: I am using crome mobile browser and playbackRate function is working fine in desktop version but not supported mobile version. If it is not working in mobile then can please give me alternative solution (if you know then).